# Customize work item : found in release & resolved in release not populated

Tags: tfs

In TFS2010 I am customizing the CMMI template. I want to have 2 value-lists for "Found in build" and "Resolved in build" custom fields.

The suggested values must be taken from the builds that are populated by TFS in a globallist.

How can this be done to get it work ?

Answer (score 0):

In the WorkItemType definition, edit the `Found In Build` and `Resolved In Build` fields to have an `ALLOWEDVALUES` of one of the "Builds" fields in the global list.  For example, if you have ProjectA and ProjectB, and you wanted your fields to have those in a dropdown, set the `ALLOWEDVALUES` to `GLOBALLIST: Builds - ProjectA`  and  `GLOBALLIST: Builds - ProjectB`

That will give you the dropdown list.  Be careful, though, as those lists can get huge, and quickly!